# Why href doesn't work inside nav tabs in boostrap v4?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="page1" role="tab">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="page2" role="tab" >Profile</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="page3" role="tab" >Messages</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="page2" role="tab">Settings</a>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content col-9" id="v-pills-tabContent">
      </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I use boostrap4, and want to do a left navigation panel as the above example.
But I found that when I click each tab, the href does not work? I refer [boostrap documents](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. When you click any tab, there is no content to match inside **`tab-content`**, from where the text are actually shown.
2. You have to set the corresponding `id` of the content to the related tab's `href` by prefixing `#`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#page1" role="tab">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#page2" role="tab" >Profile</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#page3" role="tab" >Messages</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#page4" role="tab">Settings</a>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content col-9" id="v-pills-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="page1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">Home content...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="page2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">Profile content...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="page3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">Messages content...</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="page4" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">Settings content...</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the tab content.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#v-pills-tab

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-page-1" data-toggle="pill" href="#page1" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-page-1" aria-selected="true">Page 1</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-page-2" data-toggle="pill" href="#page2" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-page-2" aria-selected="false">Page 2</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-page-3" data-toggle="pill" href="#page3" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-page-3" aria-selected="false">Page 3</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-page-4" data-toggle="pill" href="#page4" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-page-4" aria-selected="false">Page 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content col-9" id="v-pills-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="page1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-page-1">page 1 content</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="page2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-page-2">page 2 content</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="page3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-page-3">page 3 content</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="page4" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-page-4">page 4 content</div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```